# Unmarried Madam

Tags: grammatical-gender

In Spanish there is *senora* and *senorita*, in French there is *madame* and *mademoiselle* and in English there is mrs and miss. My question is that in English we also have call women "Madam" or "Ma'am" as a similar title. I was wondering if the English "madam" can only be used for a married women and if there was another form of the word for different types of women, like married and unmarried.

Comment: I would say it goes by perceived seniority/status.  A younger woman might be called Miss.

Comment: In US English the meanings of "madam" and "ma'am" are reasonably interchangeable and may be used for a married or single woman.  However, "madam" is considerably more formal and "stiff" (and can be taken as an insult if used inappropriately), and both are falling into disuse.

Comment: Are you asking about current or historical usage? [Recent research](http://www.geog.cam.ac.uk/research/projects/occupations/abstracts/paper25.pdf) has shown that *Miss*, *Mrs*, and *Ms* did not primarily reflect marital status until the nineteenth century.

Comment: @HotLicks I think you should expand upon *ma'am*. I think it really answers the question (at least for AmE)

Comment: Apart from any other context if I heard “unmarried madam” I’d think the owner of a house ill-repute had enough men without needing one at home too.

Answer (score 5):

In US English, when, say, a store clerk addresses the next person at the counter, he might say "May I help you, ma'am?"  That is, "ma'am" is the female equivalent of "sir" and serves as a stand-in for a person's name when the name is not known.  A more formal term, especially if the woman is noticeably older or of higher status than the speaker, is "madam" (though the term carries other connotations and could be taken as an insult if perceived to be used sarcastically).  Neither term carries an implication as to marital status.

If the female person is much younger than the speaker, and especially if less than about 18 years old, the term "miss" may be used instead of "ma'am".  However, note that it carries a weak implication of being unmarried.

I suspect that both terms (and "sir") are slowly falling into disuse.

Of course, if addressed by one's last name, Miss/Mrs./Ms. would be used, much as it is in written address form:  "John, this is Ms. Smith.  I told her you could help her with her tax problems."

Comment: But whether such terms are 'falling into disuse' or not, one is still faced with what to call someone whose name you don't know - and I for one would always use *sir* and *madam*. In France I would use *monsieur*, *madame*, and (for a young woman) *mademoiselle*. But I would not use *miss* in English.

Comment: @WS2 - The use of *madam* is quite rare in the US.